# Transform Western codepage to Windows 1251

Tags: delphi

I try to load Cyrillic web page (default codepage Western) and put it to TMemo component.

But I see "Âûñòàâêè" instead of "Выставки" in Memo.

How to transform string from Western to Windows 1251 codepage?

Delphi XE 8 sp1

Comment: SHow your code, how do you load the web page?

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. You don't use 1251. You use Unicode. Step 1, find out how the input text is encoded.

Comment: Are we in the 1980s again?

Comment: "I try to load Cyrillic web page (default codepage Western)" - the web page should declare its codepage so defaults do not matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TMemo` (and most of the RTL/VCL/FMX in general) in XE8 expects `UnicodeString` data in UTF-16 format.  You would have to decode the webpage data from its actual charset (which is presumably already Windows-1251, as it does not make sense for Russian text to be encoded in Windows-1252) to UTF-16 before then loading it into the `TMemo`.  The actual charset used for the raw data needs to be reported in the HTTP `Content-Type` header, or in the HTML itself.

You would not decode the raw data to Windows 1251.  That would have been necessary only if you were using a pre-Unicode version of Delphi (2007 and earlier) running your app on a Windows Russian machine that uses Windows-1251 as its default codepage.  Those days are gone in a Unicode environment like XE8.

Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed.  Indy's `TIdHTTP` component handles the charset-to-UTF16 decoding for you, eg:

```
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(URL);
```

If you download the webpage data any other way, you would have to download it as raw bytes and decode them yourself, such as by using `TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251)` followed by `TEncoding.GetString()`.  Or, if the bytes are in a `TStream`, you can use `Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream()` specifying `TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251)` as the encoding.

Comment: Remy, thanks a lot. 

This is works code:
<blink>
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  s : string;
  r : TBytes;
begin
    s := 'Âûñòàâêè';
    r := TEncoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s);
    ShowMessage(TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(r));// BytesOf
end;  </blink>

Comment: `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` returns a new `TEncoding` object that you need to `Free()` when you are done using it: `var Win1252: TEncoding; begin Win1252 := TEncoding.GetEncoding(1252); try ... finally Win1252.Free; end; end;`  Same with 1251.

Answer (score -2):

```
type
  TSrcStr = type AnsiString(1251);
  TDstStr = type AnsiString(1252);

function Decode(const s: string): string;
var
  a: TSrcStr;
  b: TDstStr;
begin
  setlength(a, length(s));
  b := s;
  move(b[low(b)], a[low(a)], length(b)*sizeof(b[low(b)]));
  result := a;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Âûñòàâêè';
  s := Decode(s);
  Assert(s='Выставки');
end;
```

Comment: This isn't really how you are meant to do this. This code is predicated on you mistreating the data. If it's 1251, treat it as such. Likewise if it's 1252. But don't treat 1251 as though it is 1252 or vice versa.

Comment: @David I don't understand what do you mean. Original text was converted from 1-byte encoding to unicode incorrectly (with wrong codepage). I suggested simple decoding function. You can check it in few seconds (in unicode Delphi with unicode memo). If he get it from external webpages, than it is already treated in wrong way and i see only one way to restore. Do you see better solution?

Comment: I think we should start by seeing the askers code. I'd expect to see TEncoding in use here FWIW. The better solution is not to mistreat the data in the first place. Even if you do mistreat it, there's no need to go from mistreated ansistring to correct ansistring to Unicode string. You can avoid the guy in the middle.

Comment: why not use SetCodePage function ?  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SetCodePage

Comment: Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Andy If you think this is your answer, then you have not understood the problem yet.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. But this function doesn't work for mobile platforms because ansistring not available. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: David maybe I'm not quite correctly described the problem, but on the decision of Andrei partly helped me. My problem is the conversion of data.

Comment: @AndyBirtman If you really want help, you'll address the comments in the question. You'll read Remy's answer. Anyway, you accepted this answer. That is likely to make all your helpers go away. Do let us help you.